# A question on generalized Einstein manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be  a  Riemannian  manifold. So $TM$ has a natural structure of  a  symplectic  manifold. The  zero  section is  denoted by $Z$.
We  define  a  Hamiltonian on $T^0 M=TM\setminus Z$  via $$H=\frac{Ric(V,V)}{|V|^2}$$
For  Einstein manifold this  produce the trivial Hamiltonian dynamics(All points are singularity).
But what about general case? What can be said about the critical points of this Hamiltonian?

In particular is there an example of  a manifold not admitting any Einstein structure but it admits a  metric whose above constructed Hamiltonian satisfies the following property:
All solutions are periodic or singularity. (Or all solutions remains in compact sets)

**Note:** One can go ahead and ask some questions as  follows: For  what kind of  manifolds the  geodesic flow  is  smoothly or  topological equivalents to the Hamiltonian flow associated to the Hamiltonian $Ric(V,V)$?
Can the ergodic properties of this  Hamiltonian flow  be determined in terms of the sign of curvature? Under what geometric conditions the two Hamiltonian $H_1=|V|^2$ and $H_2=Ric(V,V)$ commute wrt Poisson bracket,$\{H_1,H_2\}=0$?